# How to hide topic box on top of the chat in applozic

Tags: android, applozic

Seems like I can't find a way to hide the topic box that appears on top of applozics chat / conversation view.

I'm sure that there is option to do so, but any1 knows how ?

Thank you for the help : )

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the context based chat view

1) While starting the conversations list activity or individual chat screen   you need to make key 
**ConversationUIService.CONTEXT_BASED_CHAT** to **false** like below

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, ConversationActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra(ConversationUIService.CONTEXT_BASED_CHAT, false);
  startActivity(intent);
```

2) Add the setting **ApplozicClient.getInstance(context).setContextBasedChat(false);** in onSuccess callback  of UserLoginTask